# Neo4j indices slow when querying across 2 labels

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've got a graph where each node has label either A or B, and an index on the id property for each label:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :A(id);
CREATE INDEX ON :B(id);
```

In this graph, I want to find the node(s) with id "42", but I don't know a-priori the label. To do this I am executing the following query:

```
MATCH (n {id:"42"}) WHERE (n:A OR n:B) RETURN n;
```

But this query takes 6 seconds to complete. However, doing either of:

```
MATCH (n:A {id:"42"}) RETURN n;
MATCH (n:B {id:"42"}) RETURN n;
```

Takes only ~10ms.

Am I not formulating my query correctly? What is the right way to formulate it so that it takes advantage of the installed indices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to use both indices. `result` will be a collection of matching nodes.

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (a:B {id:"42"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (b:A {id:"42"})
RETURN
  (CASE WHEN a IS NULL THEN [] ELSE [a] END) +
  (CASE WHEN b IS NULL THEN [] ELSE [b] END)
  AS result;
```

You should use [PROFILE](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/how-do-i-profile-a-query.html) to verify that the execution plan for your neo4j environment uses the [NodeIndexSeek](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/execution-plans-starting-query.html#query-plan-node-index-seek) operation for both `OPTIONAL MATCH` clauses. If not, you can use the [USING INDEX](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-using.html#using-query-using-an-index-hint) clause to give a hint to Cypher.

Answer (score 2):

You should use UNION to make sure that both indexes are used. In your question you almost had the answer.

```
MATCH (n:A {id:"42"}) RETURN n
UNION
MATCH (n:B {id:"42"}) RETURN n
;
```

This will work. To check your query use profile or explain before your query statement to check if the indexes are used .

Answer (score 1):

Indexes are formed and and used via a node label and property, and to use them you need to form your query the same way. That means queries w/out a label will scan all nodes with the results you got.